# Mutate DF1 based on DF2 with a check

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

nubie here with a dataframe/mutate question... I want to update a dataframe (df1) based on data in another dataframe (df2). For one offs I've used MUTATE so I figure this is the way to go. Additionally I would like a check function added (TRUE/FALSE ?) to indicate if the the field in df1 was updated.

For Example..

```
df1-
 State
   <chr>
 1 N.Y. 
 2 FL   
 3 AL   
 4 MS   
 5 IL   
 6 WS   
 7 WA   
 8 N.J. 
 9 N.D. 
10 S.D. 
11 CALL 

df2
State New_State   
   <chr> <chr>       
 1 N.Y.  New York    
 2 FL    Florida     
 3 AL    Alabama     
 4 MS    Mississippi 
 5 IL    Illinois    
 6 WS    Wisconsin   
 7 WA    Washington  
 8 N.J.  New Jersey  
 9 N.D.  North Dakota
10 S.D.  South Dakota
11 CAL   California
```

I want the output to look like this

```
df3
New_State          Test
  <chr>         
 1 New York        TRUE
 2 Florida         TRUE
 3 Alabama         TRUE
 4 Mississippi     TRUE
 5 Illinois        TRUE
 6 Wisconsin       TRUE
 7 Washington      TRUE
 8 New Jersey      TRUE
 9 North Dakota    TRUE
10 South Dakota    TRUE
11 CALL            FALSE
```

In essence I want R to read the data in df1 and change df1 based on the match in df2 chaining out to the full state name and replace. Lastly if the data in df1 was update mark as "TRUE" (N.Y. to NEW YORK) and "FALSE" if not updated (CALL vs CAL)

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the result you're looking for:

```
match_vec <- match(df1$State, table = df2$State)
```

This vector should match all the abbreviated state names in df1 with those in df2. Where there's no match, you end up with a missing value:

Then the following code using `dplyr` should produce the `df3` you requested.

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(New_State = df2$New_State[match_vec]) %>% 
  mutate(Test = !is.na(match_vec)) %>% 
  mutate(New_State = ifelse(is.na(New_State), 
                            State, New_State)) %>% 
  select(New_State, Test)
```

Comment: @jayacher
This is very close to what I seek but the problem occurs in df3/line 11. 
        
    10 South Dakota  TRUE
    11         <NA> FALSE
    
I was hoping that the original erroneous entry of ”CALL” would remain and a flag of FALSE would indicate that the 2 dfs were not in sync. When inspecting df3 I lack the ability to determine the original entry and remediate it, that is change “CALL” in df1 to “CAL” and rerun to fix df3.

Comment: @TommyV - I've just fixed a small typo, so hopefully it works as required now.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: @TommyV - if the answer works for you, can you accept it so that doesn't get flagged as unanswered? Simply click the tick mark on the left side of the answer.